# Force maven to update the <latest> tag in maven-metadata.xml when deploying

Tags: xml, maven, nexus, maven-metadata

For some reason the "latest" tag in the maven-metadata.xml files stopped getting updated when new versions of their corresponding artifacts were deployed. After searching all over the internets, all I've found is plenty of people saying that Maven produces/updates this file when it's running its deploy plugin, but if that's true, it seems my maven builds have, for some reason, stopped updating the latest tag. Is there anyway to force maven to update the tag during a build/deploy?

During my build, I see these messages, clearly indicating that it's downloading maven-metadata.xml, I assume updating it, then uploading it back to the server:

```
Downloading: https://<REPO_SERVER>/<ARTIFACT_PATH>/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://<REPO_SERVER>/<ARTIFACT_PATH>/maven-metadata.xml (955 B at 3.0 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://<REPO_SERVER>/<ARTIFACT_PATH>/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: https://<REPO_SERVER>/<ARTIFACT_PATH>/maven-metadata.xml (989 B at 1.5 KB/sec)
```

Comment: What version of Maven is this?

Comment: Maven is not responsible for changing <latest> tag information, its only update <release> tag. <latest> tag has been added and updated by Nexus itself. give some more input to understand problem